# VB.net Downloading into memory and running

Tags: vb.net, memory, streaming, download

With my new client which is linked with an IP Board forum. Once they log into the client the people who donated or bought VIP on my forums will have access to all my applications I have made. It will most likely show a list of all my applications in a listbox/listview.

I currently do not have the code to be able to do this nor do I know how to do this at all. I basically need to download a program into memory and run it from memory so my application will never touch the users hard drive. I would also need this connection to be encrypted by either packet encryption or SSL. If packet encryption is possible I would like to know as I can't find any examples of it in VB.net

Comment: Might I ask what this is for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default when you download a file you are going to only have it in memory unless you send it to a FileStream. If you are downloading on an SSL connection then yes it will be encrypted.

I feel like your question is so vague without much code brought to the table that if I answer with more detail it will be wasted unless I give you the complete code which I'm not prepared to do. Provide some more detail and I will reciprocate.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's a .Net assembly, you cannot run an EXE directly from memory.

What are you trying to do?